# How to get pointer of object created with reflect.New() in golang

Tags: pointers, go

I have a function which must accept object type. Then it must unmarshal XML to an object of a given type.

Getting object type with reflect:

```
objType := reflect.TypeOf(CustomObjectType{})
UnmarshalWorker(objType)
```

Unmarshal function:

```
func UnmarshalFeedGeneric (data []byte,objType reflect.Type) {
    unm := reflect.New(objType)
    err := xml.Unmarshal(data, unm.Interface())
}
```

And 'unm' always return nil value.

```
fmt.Println(unm)
fmt.Println(unm.Elem())
fmt.Println(unm.Interface())
```

Output:

```
<*main.CustomObjectType Value>
<main.CustomObjectType Value>
&{ <nil>   0}
```

Comment: It should work. Make sure your xml unmarshals correctly first, otherwise it will just silently fail since there's no error for valid xml that doesn't unmarshal, http://play.golang.org/p/xoRVF01x7X

Comment: Thank you! I double checked a code and found a mistake in other place. Now all works fine.